# How can i use exoPlayer in Recycler view (Multiple videos) ? How to read video title , url from list or Array?

Tags: android, postgresql, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a code that reads title and url from firebase database and works pretty well, but i need to upload url and title in Array or list .

Here is Main Activity.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Application;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView2;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase2;
    DatabaseReference mref2;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
//       getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Videos");


        mRecyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.video_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirebaseDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mref2 = mFirebaseDatabase2.getReference("videos");


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model2> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model2>()
                        .setQuery(mref2,Model2.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model2,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model2, ViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model2 model) {

                        holder.setDetails2(getApplication(),model.getName(),model.getUrl());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);


                        return new ViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }



}
```

This is my ViewHolder.Java class.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Log;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    PlayerView playerView;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void setDetails2(final Application ctx, String name, final String url) {
        TextView mTitleTv2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv2);
        playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ep_video_view);


        mTitleTv2.setText(name);
        try {
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(ctx).build();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = (SimpleExoPlayer) ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(ctx);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("video");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(video, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ViewHolder2", "exoplayer error" + e.toString());
        }


    }

}
```

THis is my Member.java/Model2 class,

```
class Model2 {

    String name,url;
    public Model2(){}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

If the videos are saved in firebase storage and we read videos metadata from firebase database , the app works pretty well, but i need to use Postgresql , and i will be using HTTP api for that, what changings i will have to make ? If anybody can provide an example of taking video metadata from array or a list, i think i can handle other work.

Thank you